# handmade and autogenerated makefiles fail under windows but work on unix

Tags: c, netbeans, makefile, codeblocks

I have a project that will compile fine with a hand made basic makefile under unix, but does not work with either netbeans or code::blocks under windows. This will obviously make the project exceedingly difficult to debug. I have tried using my handmade makefile in place of the automatically generated one and I still get the errors list below.

```
In file included from Graph.h:7:0,
                 from main.cpp:9:
List.h:37:6: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’
List.h:40:16: error: variable or field ‘printList’ declared void
List.h:40:16: error: ‘FILE’ was not declared in this scope
List.h:40:22: error: ‘out’ was not declared in this scope
List.h:40:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘L’
```

The makefile I have made is:

```
BASE_SOURCES   = Graph.c List.c
BASE_OBJECTS   = Graph.o List.o
HEADERS        = Graph.h List.h
COMPILE        = gcc -c -std=c99 -Wall
LINK           = gcc -o
REMOVE         = rm -f
MEMCHECK       = valgrind --leak-check=full

GraphClient : GraphClient.o $(BASE_OBJECTS)
    $(LINK) GraphClient GraphClient.o $(BASE_OBJECTS)

FindPath.o : FindPath.c $(HEADERS)
    $(COMPILE) FindPath.c

GraphClient.o : GraphClient.c $(HEADERS)
    $(COMPILE) GraphClient.c

$(BASE_OBJECTS) : $(BASE_SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    $(COMPILE) $(BASE_SOURCES)

clean :
    $(REMOVE) GraphClient GraphClient.o $(BASE_OBJECTS)

checkClient : GraphClient
    $(MEMCHECK) GraphClient
```

I can include the netbeans generated makefile if anyone wants, but I don't think that matters since my handmade one does not work under windows either. Same for the actual code, I don't think it really matters since it compiles under unix?

Comment: `.o` file is only valid on unix based systems. you should have `.dll` files as your dynamic link libraries. Besides, gcc is not available on windows. I guess these hys are using mingw or vc...

Comment: That's not correct. The `.o` file is the format used for intermediate-step object files, and is used that way on windows and Unix. The `.dll` is equivalent to `.so` on Unix.

Comment: If that were correct, presumably the errors I would get would not be related to the code specifically? Code::blocks and netbeans both use the windows version of gcc to compile provided under cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting syntax errors reported by gcc when compiling a header file. The most likely cause for this is a difference in the contents of one of the standard header files between Linux and Windows. What does the code around line 37 of `List.h` look like?

Note also that gcc is complaining about `FILE` not being declared on line 40. This implies that `stdio.h` is included by another header file before this point on Linux, but is not being included on Windows.